# MC (Midnight Commmander) mc.ini settings file location

Tags: mc

After installing Midnight Commander in CentOS 7, I looked for the configuration file in `/home/$USER/.mc.ini` but didn't find it. I want to change my default skin to another color scheme, but can't find config file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in the following file: `~/.config/mc/ini`.

Comment: Unfortunately not...

Comment: @alexkowalski then it's `~/.config/mc/ini`

Answer (score 0):

If you have not made any changes, the config file does not yet exist.

The easy way to change from the default skin:

1. Start Midnight Commander

   ```
   sudo mc
   ```
2. <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> for Options, or cursor to "Options" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. <kbd>A</kbd> for Appearance, or cursor to Appearance and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   You will see that default is the current skin.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see the other skin choices
5. Cursor to the skin you want and select it by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Click OK

After you do this, the ini file will exist and can be edited, but it is easier to change skins using the method I described.

Comment: There is no Appearance menu under Options.

Comment: Nope, indeed... 4.8.7-11.el7